# Make the git repo part of the drupal site so I can commit my changes whilst testing

Tags: users, drush, installation

I've got a git repo on my desktop with a couple of make files. I am currently building the drupal site in my htdocs folder by copying the distro.make file there, running the command:
 `drush make distro.make geoslate_test --working-copy --no-gitinfofile`

and then cding into the geoslate_test folder and running:

```
drush si vimn_geoslate --db-url='mysql://root:root@localhost/geo_test' --site-name=Geoslate
```

to install drupal.

I would like instead to have the git repo as part of the drupal site, so that I can commit my changes whilst testing on the site build install.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: I believe that solving my problem is something to do with using aliases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I cd into the profiles folder on the Drupal site that has been installed as above, and then commit changes, and push them to git, it also works as if I was committing them from the folder on the desktop which I initially ran the git init on. I read something that said that Drush automatically knows that you are in the directory of a Drupal install, so perhaps this is the resolution.